# Grid like control with cell level customization for .net

Tags: wpf, winforms, grid

I am looking for a grid like control either WinForm or WPF.
I have collection of a array of class named `PropertyInfo`. This class exposes `PropertyValue` and `PropertyType` as properties. `PropertyValue` can be any arbitrary object.This collection of array need to be shown in grid layout , where I need to have control on each cell. For example based on `PropertyType` , the cell could be combobox or checkbox or hyperlink cell or even could be a readonly. So I need create cells in code-behind by iterating collection and array values in each item. 
Other requirements are :

1. Should be a free or standard .net control.
2. Should be supported in .net 3.5.
3. Should support hosting custom control in  cell to edit cell value.
   Ex: Color Picker to edit color.
4. Should notify value change to  perform extra validations like max
   text length or numeric range.
5. Should allow to retrieve cell values which are modified.
6. It would be nice if cell properties like border, foreground and
   background color can be defined.

In my search I came across WinForm DataGridView. This control is more suitable if data is in DataSet and combobox is available when a column type is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. Not sure if combobox can be placed randomly in any cell via code. Another control named Sourcegrid is on [codeplex](http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/). Not sure if it can full fill all above requirements. Please provide suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen the extended WPF toolkit's [`PropertyGrid`](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home)?

Comment: `So I need create cells in code-behind by iterating collection and array values in each item.` - No you don't. That's not how you do things in WPF. in WPF you create a proper `DataTemplate` for each specific `DataType` and let the UI "draw" and manage itself. unlike winforms, WPF is not a useless dinosaur and doesn't need a bunch of horrible hacks to get anything done. It also does not need anything from `System.Data` and can bind ANY properties from ANY UI element to ANY data object or ANY other UI element. In short it's much more capable of everything.

Comment: What you're describing here can be achieved with some 15 lines of XAML for an `ItemsControl` and a couple of `DataTemplates`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In case of wpf suppose one property value is collection of abstract type.And derived types have their own specific properties which are not defined at abstract base level.And I need to know the type first and then need to decide which property is to render. Here I do not have any control on types to be rendered , like implementing a INotifyPropertyChanged. So these types and their collections are not WPF binding friendly. I know its ugly way to write code to do all in code-behind.But that seems to be the only way.